# Change Entity State

Tags: entity-framework

I currently have an entity model with a bunch of deleted items, the state is deleted. Is there a way to "undelete" them? I know which Items I want to undelete, but I don't know how to undelete the items. Ideally I'd like to get it back to an unchanged state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the option of just not committing the connection context?  - dispose the ObjectContext without calling objectContext.SaveChanges();  Of course, if you have certain changes that you do wan't saved, they will not persist either.

If you called `objectContext.DeleteObject(x)` you can't undelete it and still save changes.

```
ObjectStateEntry objectStateEntry = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(x);

// objectStateEntry.State is not setable
```

ObjectStateEntry does have the OriginalValues property so you could, in theory, painstakingly recreate a collection that represents the original changes, minus the unwanted ones, exit the objectContext, open a new one and rebuild those changes minus the unwanted ones there.  Probably not worth the hassle, but there is no documented way to unmark something for deletion at this time.

Comment: That's too bad. I had a feeling there is no way. Unfortunately we can't just clear out the context, so that's not really an option. Right now I have implemented a list of objects that are to be modified before being removed. It's actually a really big hassle and it's too bad that something can't be marked as unchanged.

Comment: Entity Framework Design blog http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/ says:

"...self-tracking entities architecture that will ship along side of VisualStudio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.0."
"...
There are conveience methods on each self-tracking entity to change this state if needed (Delete() and SetUnchanged())."

So it looks like this ability will be available in EF2

Answer (score 8):

after you call

**objectContext.DeleteObject(x)**,

you can simulate undelete of object **x** with

**objectContext.Detach(x); objectContext.Attach(x)**

Answer (score 0):

you can implement RejectChanges method for your Context, ObjectSet or EntityObject.
Now I write VB Code of these methods:
Extension method for RejectChanges in Context:

```
<Extension()>
Sub RejectChanges(ByVal Context As ObjectContext)
    Dim Collectin As IEnumerable(Of Object) = From e In Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Modified Or System.Data.EntityState.Deleted) Select e.Entity
    Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, Collectin)

    Dim AddedCollection As IEnumerable(Of Object) = From e In Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added) Select e.Entity
    For Each addedEntity As Object In AddedCollection
        Context.Detach(addedEntity)
    Next
End Sub
```

Extension mehod for implementing RejectChanges in ObjectSet:

```
<Extension()>
Sub RejectChanges(Of T As MyEntity)(ByVal Lst As ObjectSet(Of T))
    Dim collection As IEnumerable(Of T) = From o In Lst.AsEnumerable() Where o.EntityState = EntityState.Modified Or o.EntityState = EntityState.Deleted Select o
    Lst.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, collection)

    Dim AddedCollection As IEnumerable(Of T) = (From e In Lst.Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added) Select e.Entity).ToList().OfType(Of T)()
    For Each entity As T In AddedCollection
        Lst.Context.Detach(entity)
    Next
End Sub
```

and finally implementing RejectChanges for EntityObject:

```
<Extension()>
Sub RejectChanges(ByVal entity As EntityObject, ByVal Context As ObjectContext)
    If entity.EntityState = EntityState.Modified OrElse entity.EntityState = EntityState.Deleted Then
        Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity)
    ElseIf entity.EntityState = EntityState.Added Then
        Context.Detach(entity)
    End If
End Sub
```

bye.
[Iman Shabanzade]